# Is there a legit reason as to why Outlook.com premium UI is "not available" in Linux Chrome?

Tags: windows

Well if you use outlook OWA in Chrome on Ubuntu (or any Linux distro), you will get a stripped down version of it basically.

You can get around it by faking your user agent, to appear that you are using FireFox.

So my question is.. Is there some legitimate reason Microsoft does that, or are they just being a******s???

I mean once you have the user agent faked, it works perfectly.

PS. Just in case anyone else need to use outlook, here is the command to start it with fake useragent:

/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.481.0 Safari/534.4"

Comment: Does it work? Then there is no technical reason that I can think of.

Comment: It does yeah. Well I cannot think any either.. That is what made me curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there's a legit reason. It helps Microsoft promote their OS  over Linux and they have no obligation to support competitors. This is [Bug # 1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1) and they don't owe us any favors, simple as that.

A radio host I listened to used to say to irate callers 'Don't go away mad, just go away'. That's good advice, I took it and left Windows for Ubuntu and I don't worry about what Microsoft is doing.